# google apps script spreadsheet servicess appendrow double entry

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using GAS to write data to a spreadsheet and everything works as expected except for the part where it saves the record TWICE each time.  I don't think the client or server functions are firing twice so it could something else I missed.  Any insight would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

The client function:

```
//save data
function savedata() {
  var data = $('#dataSetter');
  var startTime = data.find('#startTime').val();
  var firstName = data.find('#firstName').val();
  var lastName = data.find('#lastName').val();
  var phone = data.find('#phone').val();
  var email = data.find('#email').val();
  var obj = $(this).parent();
  var weekDate = getSuffix(obj.attr('id'));
      weekDate = weekDate.replace('-', '/');
  var year = getSuffix(obj.attr('class'));
  var date = weekDate+'/'+year;

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dataSaved).setdata(office, firstName, lastName, phone, email, date, startTime);
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).setdata(office, firstName, lastName, phone, email, date, startTime);
}
```

The server function:

```
//saves data
function setdata(office, firstName, lastName, phone, email, date, startTime) {
  var dataSheet = dataBook.getSheets()[0];
  var membersSheet = membersBook.getSheets()[0];
  var membersLastRow = membersSheet.getLastRow();

  var lastmemberID = membersSheet.getRange('A'+membersLastRow).getValue();

  var newmemberID = memberID(lastmemberID);

  membersSheet.appendRow([newmemberID, lastName, firstName, phone, email]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making two calls to setdata function, so double entries should be expected. Try this:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dataSaved).withFailureHandler(onFailure).setdata(office, firstName, lastName, phone, email, date, startTime);
```

instead of:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(dataSaved).setdata(office, firstName, lastName, phone, email, date, startTime);
  google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).setdata(office, firstName, lastName, phone, email, date, startTime);
```

Comment: That solved it!

The examples in the GAS documentation didn't mention that it needs to be chained. At least I didn't see it.  Thanks @jad.

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced tbsi bug many times though sporadically.
It inserts twice as many rows as i requested. I have all that code protected with a lock (lock services, which u should use too since u use getastrow and such) so i know the code is not getting run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for that tip Zig.  I will try it now.

By using Lock services, did the bug go away completely for you?

Comment: I inserted lock services (below but not sure if it's correct) but the problem still persists:

`// Get a public lock on this script, because we're about to modify a shared resource.
   var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
   // Wait for up to 30 seconds for other processes to finish.
   lock.waitLock(30000);  
   
  membersSheet.appendRow([newmemberID, lastName, firstName, phone, email]);

   // Release the lock so that other processes can continue.
   lock.releaseLock();`